# MySQL -> Transaction Context -> Code Review

Tags: c#, mysql

I am hoping someone could check my context of how I am using Transaction with MySql.  I believe this should work with the outline below.  Can someone look at my code and tell me if I am doing it correctly?  Thank you.

I believe this should:

- Instantiate the db connection.
- Iterate through the DataTable rows of the given DataTable.
- Check to see if the table exists and if it does not it will Execute the Create Table.
- Execute Insert Command with Parameters of information into the newly created or existing table.
- Commit the Transaction and then close the connection.

  ```
      //Open the SQL Connection
      var dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString(WowDatabase));
      dbConnection.Open();
      //Instantiate the Command
      using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
      {
          //Create a new Transaction
          using (var transaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction())
          {
              uint lastId = 999999;
              for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                  //var identifier = dt.Rows[i].Field<int>("Identifier");
                  var id = dt.Rows[i].Field<uint>("Entry");
                  var name = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>("Name");
                  var zone = dt.Rows[i].Field<uint>("ZoneID");
                  var map = dt.Rows[i].Field<uint>("MapID");
                  var state = dt.Rows[i].Field<Enums.ItemState>("State");
                  var type = dt.Rows[i].Field<Enums.ObjectType>("Type");
                  var faction = dt.Rows[i].Field<Enums.FactionType>("Faction");
                  var x = dt.Rows[i].Field<float>("X");
                  var y = dt.Rows[i].Field<float>("Y");
                  var z = dt.Rows[i].Field<float>("Z");
                  string dataTableName = "entry_" + id;
                  //Create Table if it does not exist.
                  if (id != lastId)
                  {
                      cmd.CommandText = $"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{dataTableName}` (" +
                                        "`identifier`   int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Auto Incriment Identifier' ," +
                                        "`zone_id`      int NULL COMMENT 'Zone Entry' ," +
                                        "`x_axis`       float NULL COMMENT 'X Axis on Map' ," +
                                        "`y_axis`       float NULL COMMENT 'Y Axis on Map' ," +
                                        "`z_axis`       float NULL COMMENT 'Z Axis on Map' ," +
                                        "`situation`    enum('') NULL COMMENT 'Location of the item. Underground, Indoors, Outdoors)' ," +
                                        "`faction`      enum('') NULL COMMENT 'Specifies the Faction which can safely access the item.' ," +
                                        "PRIMARY KEY(`identifier`)" +
                                        ")";
                      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      lastId = id;
                  }
                  //Create command to execute the insertion of Data into desired Table
                  cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO [{dataTableName}] " +
                                         "([identifier], [zone_id], [x_axis], [y_axis], [z_axis], [situation], [faction], [Create_Date], [Update_Date]) " +
                                         "VALUES (@Identifier, @Zone_Id, @X_Axis, @Y_Axis, @Z_Axis, @Situation, @Faction, @Create_Date, @Update_Date)";
                  //Add data value with Parameters.
                  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                  //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Identifier", identifier);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Identifier", id);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone_Id", zone);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@X_Axis", x);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Y_Axis", y);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Z_Axis", z);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Situation", state);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Faction", faction);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Create_Date", DateTime.Now.Date);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Update_Date", DateTime.Now.Date);

                  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              } //for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)

              //Commit the Transaction
              transaction.Commit();
          } //using (var transaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction())
      } //using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())

      //Close the Connection
      dbConnection.Close();
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consider a `using` statement**

You can actually wrap your existing `dbConnection` within a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement to ensure that it is safely disposed of (similar to how you are handling your transactions, commands, etc.) :

```
 //Open the SQL Connection
 using(var dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString(WowDatabase))
 {
      // Other code omitted for brevity
 }
```

**Consistent String Interpolation**

You have a few spots where you simply concatenate strings via `+` but you are mostly taking advantage of C# 6's String Interpolation feature. You might want to consider using it everywhere :

```
 string dataTableName = $"entry_{id}";
```

**No Need for Setting `CommandType`**

Additionally, you could remove the the setting of your `CommandType` property for your actual `cmd` object as `CommandType.Text` is the default :

```
 //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have added the changes.  So syntax aside, was my use of Transaction correct?  Would it execute the sql commands with in the iteration and then commit them once the for loop is done?

Comment: Assuming that the issue that John brought up isn't a problem (with the commits being triggered by the `CREATE TABLE` calls), it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work (as expected) with MySql.  There are a few statements that cause an implicit commit - `CREATE TABLE` is one of them.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: Interesting.  I was refactoring this from SQL CE and I guess that does not come over verbatim.  Thank you for bringing this to my attention!  I have a work around for this using  "Select table_name from information_schema.tables".  Will this work in MySQL?

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work. Just know that the table will be created before you do the `transaction.Commit()`.

Comment: I misunderstood what your answer was initially.  Thank you for pointing this out!